# jQuery how to select column in table based on table heading

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to figure out how to select a column in a table based on the table heading. What I have figured out, with lots of googling, so far is this:

```
<html>
<body>
   <table>
      <tr><th class='x29'>A</th><th class='x29'>B</th><th class='x29'>C</th><th class='x29'>D</th></tr>
      <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
      <tr><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
      <tr><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
   </table>
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
          var l_col;
          $('th.x29').each(function () {
             if ($(this).text() == 'C') {
                l_col = $(this).index();
                $(this).closest('tr').next().children().eq(l_col+1).append("<b>A String</b>");
             }
          });
       });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately this only appends "A String" to the first row of the column for which the heading is "C". How can I append "A String" to the entire column for which the heading is "C". Better code than mine would be appreciated.

Comment: then closest may not be right choice then.

Comment: What would you recommend instead?

Comment: have you try with find or other filter

Comment: I'm afraid it's my first day with jQuery

Comment: then its good that you start up reading with jquery selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the nth cell of every row by using a combination of `contains`, `index` and `nth:child` selector.

Code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("tr td:nth-child(" + ($('th.x29:contains("C")').index()+1) + ")").append("<b>A String</b>")
  });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/VWr7X/

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var l_col  = $('th.x29').filter(function(){
        return $(this).text() === 'C';
    }).index() +1 ;

    $('tr td:nth-child(' + l_col + ')').append('<b>A String</b>');

});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/HfjLa/